# Why FOR LOOP only output Echo is on in txt file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo, wmi, wmic

My cmd batch file always output:

> ```
> ECHO is on.
> ECHO is on.
> ECHO is on.
> ```

The script:

```
SET "InputFile=abc.txt"
IF EXIST "%InputFile%" (DEL /f /q "%InputFile%")
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F Tokens^=* %%G IN ('
    "WMIC PATH Win32_DiskPartition WHERE ^(DeviceID^="Disk #0, Partition #1"^) Assoc:list /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL"

') DO (CALL ECHO %%G>> "%InputFile%")

ENDLOCAL
```

How to fix?.

Comment: You need to be clear what exactly you want to be output to `%InputFile%`.

Comment: WMIC output is unicode. Pass through `More` to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The [`WHERE` clause in *WQL*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/where-clause) fails if contains a comma. Use

```
"… WHERE ^(DeviceID^ like^ "Disk #0_ Partition #1"^) …
```

**2.** There is a known `wmic` bug, see [Dave Benham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)'s article [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266). Fix it e.g. as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "InputFile=abc56715419.txt"
IF EXIST "%InputFile%" (DEL /f /q "%InputFile%")
REM SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(
FOR /F Tokens^=* %%G IN ('
    "WMIC PATH Win32_DiskPartition WHERE ^(DeviceID^ like^ "Disk #0_ Partition #1"^) Assoc:list /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL"
') DO ( for /F "delims=" %%g in ("%%G") do (CALL ECHO(%%g))
)>>"%InputFile%"
REM debugging output
type "%InputFile%"
ENDLOCAL
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `WMIC` output;
- `%%g` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the values returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is simply with the `DeviceID` string containing a comma, this can easily be overcome using a variable to hold it. In order not to return `Echo` status messages, you need to add a non space character after `Echo`, the best chartacters for doing that are `(`, `=` and `/`.

Try this!

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=abc.txt"
Set "SearchStr=Disk #0, Partition #1"

If Exist "%InputFile%" Del /F "%InputFile%"
For /F Tokens^=* %%A In ('
    "WMIC Partition Where (DeviceID="%%SearchStr%%") Assoc:List /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL"
')Do >>"%InputFile%" Echo(%%A
```

If you don't want to have empty lines in your file output then use another nested `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "InputFile=abc.txt"
Set "SearchStr=Disk #0, Partition #1"

If Exist "%InputFile%" Del /F "%InputFile%"
For /F Tokens^=* %%A In ('
    "WMIC Partition Where (DeviceID="%%SearchStr%%") Assoc:List /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL"
')Do For /F Tokens^=* %%B In ("%%A")Do >>"%InputFile%" Echo(%%B
```

However as you're outputting everything, there's no need for a `For` loop at all:

```bat
@Set "InputFile=abc.txt"
@Set "SearchStr=Disk #0, Partition #1"
@If Exist "%InputFile%" Del /F "%InputFile%"
@WMIC /Output:"%InputFile%" Partition Where (DeviceID="%SearchStr%") Assoc:List /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL
```

**[Edit /]**

As this is one of many questions all seemingly based around the same task, if you're only trying to determine the drive letter associated with `Disk #0, Partition #1` you can do that similarly:

```bat
@Set "SearchStr=Disk #0, Partition #1"
@For /F Skip^=2Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('"WMIC Partition Where (DeviceID="%%SearchStr%%") Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %SearchStr% = %%A
```